# Install openssh >=v8.2

Tags: cygwin, openssh, mobaxterm

How is it possible to install openssh >=v8.2 into [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) (cygwin environment)?

```
apt-get install openssh
```

will return only

```
- openssh v7.9p1-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cygwin setup to install it

the last version available of openssh is 8.4p1-2

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/openssh.html

Comment: I also tried it with apt-cyg, but then MobaXTerm complained that the package can not be modified due to openssh is a core package.

But it works, when I execute the package update with setup-x86.exe and pointing to mobaXTerm cygwin root dir.

Many thanks